# Is there a way to capture the routing used for an HTTP error with in flask?

Tags: python, flask, error-handling

I'm working on a flask web app and I'm trying to integrate more meaningful dimensions for when errors occur so I can troubleshoot them. Right now, I have 404, 401, and 500 errors being written to a log, but I have no way of knowing what endpoint triggered the error.

For example, when user goes to https://www.mywebsite.com/this-page-doesnt-exist and they get a 404 error, I want to know they tried to visit "this-page-doesnt-exist"

Comment: @mechanical_meat you're absolutely right, it is, thank you

Comment: You're welcome. I will close this question, then.